# Alexa Smart Home Skill - Use Lambda to just forward events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, forwarding

I'm building an Alexa Smart Home skill.

Each of my users owns a hub device in their homes which is maintains an permanently open connection to my servers.

Now, Smart Home Skills require the usage of AWS Lambda, which I actually do not want to use, since I already have my own servers.
The idea is to use Lambda to just forward every incoming event to my servers via https and answering all requests asynchronously.
Since I imagine there are other people that want to forward lambda calls to their own servers, I wonder if there is already open source software for doing just that?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use your Lambda as a pass-through or proxy, send the request to your server to send an [asynchronous response](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/alexa-response.html#response).

However, another approach could be to handle the *Alexa specific* logic in your Lambda, and then call your server/API via HTTP to just get what it needs (state/device info) for any request from Alexa. This decouples your logic better IMO, with separation of concerns.

There's no open source software to do this for you either, as essentially you'll need to map your device/state data to the format for Alexa. The [docs](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/understand-the-smart-home-skill-api.html) are pretty good though.